# No MediaQuery widget ancestor found

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'info.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<info> li = [
    info(name: 'text1', length: 170, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text2', length: 175, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text3', length: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text4', length: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text5', length: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text6', length: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text7', length: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text8', length: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
    info(name: 'text9', length: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
  ];

  void x (BuildContext ctx){
    showModalBottomSheet(context: ctx, builder: (ctx){
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: li.length,
        itemBuilder: (cx , index){
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Card(
              shadowColor: Colors.red,
              elevation: 10.0,
              color: Colors.blue,

              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          li[index].name,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${li[index].length}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${li[index].date}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App name',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('This is the App bar'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () => x(context)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

> The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: No
> MediaQuery widget ancestor found.
>
> MyApp widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor. The specific
> widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was: MyApp   state:
> MyAppState#7e07c The ownership chain for the affected widget is:
> "MyApp ← [root]"
>
> **No MediaQuery ancestor could be** found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you have
> not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those
> widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you
> use comes from a widget above those widgets.

What is wrong in my code? I have already used scaffold and MaterialApp Widgets and the instructor didn't use MediaQuery and I even don't know what that means, but it worked for him!

Comment: Where are you using MediaQuery?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a common mistake that happens when using Inherited Widgets like `MediaQuery`. Now you may not be using it explicitly but from your description it seems that Flutters' `showModalBottomSheet` method maybe using it.

The error is telling you that no MediaQuery ancestor(i.e. `WidgetsApp`, `CupertinoApp` or `MaterialApp`) could be found above `context`. It means above this `context`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 ...
}
```

and this is right because you have placed your `MaterialApp` widget just below this context and when you call `x(context)` it will look for `WidgetsApp`, `CupertinoApp` or `MaterialApp` above the `build` method.

There are 2 easy ways of solving this:

1. Create a new Stateless/Stateful widget and pass it to the `home` parameter OR
2. Use the `Builder` widget and pass it to the `home` parameter.

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App name',
      home: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) { 
      ...
      } ),
```

Both the solutions will provide you with a new `context` which will have a MediaQuery widget as its ancestor. It is always helpful to look at the Widget tree in the Widget Inspector.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning alternate solutions like WidgetsApp; it doesn't HAVE to be MaterialApp.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to do it this way

`void main() {runApp(const MaterialApp(home: RandomName() ,));}`
`

```
class RandomName extends StatefulWidget {
  const RandomName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RandomNameState createState() => _RandomNameState();
}

class _RandomNameState extends State<RandomName> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Just split your code in the home do not give scaffold directly istead give homepage and just create a homepage by extending stateful or stateless widget

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> You need to wrap it with **MaterialApp**.

```
MaterialApp( home: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage(),),);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).