# I'm learning flutter to develop a college project, but I'm having problems with two errors presented when compiling the code

Tags: android, flutter, animation, mobile, android-animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AppMenuAbas());
}

class AppMenuAbas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppMenuAbasState createState() => _AppMenuAbasState();
}

class _AppMenuAbasState extends State<AppMenuAbas> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  bool _isCollapsed = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void toggleCollapsed() {
    setState(() {
      _isCollapsed = !_isCollapsed;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App com Menu e Abas',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('App com Menu e Abas'),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: AnimatedIcon(
              icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
              progress: _tabController.animation,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_isCollapsed) {
                  _tabController.animateTo(0);
                }
                toggleCollapsed();
              });
            },
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home), text: 'Home'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.description), text: 'Texto'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.people), text: 'Pessoas'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), text: 'Chat'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            // Conteúdo da primeira aba (Home)
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Título Centralizado',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 1'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height:screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 2'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 3'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 4'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 5'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Conteúdo da segunda aba (Texto)
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Texto Extenso 1',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'Texto Extenso 2',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Conteúdo da terceira aba (Pessoas)
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: screenWidth / 3,
                    height: screenWidth / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person1.jpg'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Pessoa 1'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Botão'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Container(
                    width: screenWidth / 3,
                    height: screenWidth / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person2.jpg'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Pessoa 2'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Botão'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Container(
                    width: screenWidth / 3,
                    height: screenWidth / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person3.jpg'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Pessoa 3'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Botão'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Conteúdo da quarta aba (Chat)
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Conteúdo do Chat',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The errors shown are:

lib/main.dart:47:40: Error: The argument type 'Animation<double>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>' because 'Animation<double>?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.

-'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart'). progress: _tabController.animation, ^

lib/main.dart:13:17: Error: Field '_tabController' should be initialized because its type 'TabController' doesn't allow null.

-'TabController' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/tab_controller.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tab_controller.dart'). TabController _tabController;

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Failed to compile application.

Comment: If you use the answer from Hüseyin below, you'll still run into the unrelated problem, that you try to access MediaQuery.of(context) before you create such a context that provides a MediaQuery. You might want to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635405/no-mediaquery-widget-ancestor-found

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class AppMenuAbas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppMenuAbasState createState() => _AppMenuAbasState();
}

class _AppMenuAbasState extends State<AppMenuAbas>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  bool _isCollapsed = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
        vsync: this, length: 4);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void toggleCollapsed() {
    setState(() {
      _isCollapsed = !_isCollapsed;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App com Menu e Abas',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('App com Menu e Abas'),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: AnimatedIcon(
              icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
              progress:
                  _tabController.animation ?? AlwaysStoppedAnimation<double>(0),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_isCollapsed) {
                  _tabController.animateTo(0);
                }
                toggleCollapsed();
              });
            },
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home), text: 'Home'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.description), text: 'Texto'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.people), text: 'Pessoas'),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), text: 'Chat'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            // Conteúdo da primeira aba (Home)
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Título Centralizado',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 1'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 2'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 3'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 4'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: screenWidth / 5,
                        height: screenWidth / 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                            Text('Conteúdo 5'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Conteúdo da segunda aba (Texto)
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Texto Extenso 1',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'Texto Extenso 2',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Conteúdo da terceira aba (Pessoas)
            Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: screenWidth / 3,
                    height: screenWidth / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person1.jpg'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Pessoa 1'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Botão'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Container(
                    width: screenWidth / 3,
                    height: screenWidth / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person2.jpg'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Pessoa 2'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Botão'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Container(
                    width: screenWidth / 3,
                    height: screenWidth / 3,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person3.jpg'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Pessoa 3'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Botão'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Conteúdo da quarta aba (Chat)
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Conteúdo do Chat',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for tabController you have to say to the program you will define the tabController before you use it and we can use `late` for this. Because when screen will load in initState it will be defined.

For Animation error your value is `nullable`. And your code wants it `non-null` we can use `??` for situations like this. It means if this value is null then use this. And i add random Animation because i don't know exactly what your code does. You can edit it for your aim.

Comment: this will throw runtime error as the build function is using MediaQuery and it will fail to get the context

Answer (score 1):

try with these changes

```
late final TabController _tabController; //Using late initialisation

progress: _tabController.animation!, //Using not null operator
```

I suggest using const wherever applicable as a good practice and optimisation.

I have made few optimisation as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(AppMenuAbas());
}

class AppMenuAbas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppMenuAbasState createState() => _AppMenuAbasState();
}

class _AppMenuAbasState extends State<AppMenuAbas> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App com Menu e Abas',
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  bool _isCollapsed = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void toggleCollapsed() {
    setState(() {
      _isCollapsed = !_isCollapsed;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('App com Menu e Abas'),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
            progress: _tabController.animation!,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (_isCollapsed) {
                _tabController.animateTo(0);
              }
              toggleCollapsed();
            });
          },
        ),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: const [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home), text: 'Home'),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.description), text: 'Texto'),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.people), text: 'Pessoas'),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), text: 'Chat'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          // Conteúdo da primeira aba (Home)
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Título Centralizado',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: screenWidth / 5,
                      height: screenWidth / 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                          Text('Conteúdo 1'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: screenWidth / 5,
                      height: screenWidth / 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                          Text('Conteúdo 2'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: screenWidth / 5,
                      height: screenWidth / 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                          Text('Conteúdo 3'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: screenWidth / 5,
                      height: screenWidth / 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                          Text('Conteúdo 4'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: screenWidth / 5,
                      height: screenWidth / 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                          Text('Conteúdo 5'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Conteúdo da segunda aba (Texto)
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                Text(
                  'Texto Extenso 1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  'Texto Extenso 2',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Conteúdo da terceira aba (Pessoas)
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: screenWidth / 3,
                  height: screenWidth / 3,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person1.jpg'),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      const Text('Pessoa 1'),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text('Botão'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  width: screenWidth / 3,
                  height: screenWidth / 3,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person2.jpg'),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      const Text('Pessoa 2'),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text('Botão'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  width: screenWidth / 3,
                  height: screenWidth / 3,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 1),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/person3.jpg'),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      const Text('Pessoa 3'),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text('Botão'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Conteúdo da quarta aba (Chat)
          const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Conteúdo do Chat',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, i copied the code and i thought there was a use case for his program that he wrote like this. and solved it with my own way but you are right this is real correct answer.